# How to add many values at once in Apex?

Tags: apex, list, java, collection

I have a list like that:

List l = new List();

l.add('a');

l.add('b');

l.add('1');

l.add('2');

l.add('3');

How can I add all those values at once without using so many add methods?
In Java we can do List list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "1", 2", "3"));

Can we use something similar in Apex?

Answer (score 8):

You can initialize list with your items:

```
List<String> l = new List<String>{'a', 'b', 'c', 'etc'};
```